# How to add a shape in Powerpoint that calls a function (no macro)?

Tags: vba, shapes, powerpoint

im currently having problems with some visual basic stuff. I have successfully added the shape to my current Powerpoint slide using the following code:

```
dim pres as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Powerpoint
dim slide as pres.ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
With slide.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeActionButtonCustom, Left:=50, Top:= 50, Width:=70, Height:=30)
    .Name="Test"
End With
```

So what i want to do now is the function, whenever it is clicked (in presentation mode) it should call a Sub named "test()" defined in the same class. I am not able to that. All i can do for now is call a macro from the presentation using the following code:

```
dim pres as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Powerpoint
dim slide as pres.ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
With slide.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeActionButtonCustom, Left:=50, Top:= 50, Width:=70, Height:=30)
    .Name="Test"
    With .ActionSettings(PowerPoint.PpMouseActivation.ppMouseClick)
        .Run = "test"
        .Action = PowerPoint.PpActionType.ppActionRunMacro
    End With
End With
```

But since i do not have any macros in my presentation this will result in an error. When i manually add a macro using the integrated visual basic editor in powerpoint it just works the way i intended.

Is there any way to directly call a Sub from within my visual basic code without having to create a macro?

I hope i made myself clear and you guys understood my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i just stumbled upon the solution i was looking for. I did not find a way to refer an action to a powerpoint shape but instead could manage to call a function from an OLEObject. OLEObject have handlers and therefore one can simply use the click-event.

First of all you'll need to add a reference to Forms and your Visual basic for Application, simply do this by adding

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports Microsoft.Vbe.Interop
```

to your code.

Secondly you need to add an OLEObject CommandButton to your slide and add a handler to it, you can achieve this by:

```
Dim oshape As Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape = ppt.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddOLEObject(Left:=100, Top:=100, _
        Width:=150, Height:=50, ClassName:="Forms.CommandButton.1")
    With oshape.OLEFormat.Object
        .Name = "Button1"
        .Caption = "Test"
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Name = "Verdana"
        .Object.BackColor = RGB(25, 25, 50)
    End With
    AddHandler CType(oshape.OLEFormat.Object, MSForms.CommandButton).Click, _
          AddressOf Button1_Click
```

I found a very helpful answer at [vbarchiv](http://www.vbarchiv.net/forum/read.php?id=22&t=86827&i=86827&v=f).

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Is your code running from within a macro-enabled presentation or an add-in?

My understanding of what you want to do is this:

1. Programmatically add a shape to a slide, setting its action methods to run the macro "test" then clicked in slide show mode.
2. Programmatically add the macro "test" to the presentation.

If this is correct, step 2 requires the following:

1. That the presentation (.pptx) is resaved as a macro-enabled file e.g. .pptm, .potm, ppsm
2. That PowerPoint is set up to "Trust access to the VBA project object model" under File / Options / Trust Center / Trust Center Settings / Developer Macro Settings
3. That you add a reference to the Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3 library
4. That you then use the VBA object model (which requires the reference above) to the to create a code module and then insert the procedure in the VBA project. Start exploring the object model here :  ActivePresentation.VBProject

This adds a standard code module:

```
ActivePresentation.VBProject.VBComponents.Add vbext_ct_StdModule
```

This adds a procedure from a string (you can do it from a file too):

```
ActivePresentation.VBProject.VBComponents(1).CodeModule.AddFromString
```

Comment: Hi @JamieG, i appreciate your answer but this is not what i intend to do. I am working on Add-In and - if its possible - do not want to create any macros. I want the shape to execute a function from within the same class. For example: I am adding the shape with a Sub called "addShape" and want the Shape to call the sub "test()" when its clicked in the presentation